# matrix of hexbin plots with common bin/legend breaks

Tags: r, plot

Suppose I have a number of replications of bivariate experiments which I wish to display simultaneously in hexagonally binned plots, with common cell counts. Is there existing code to do this? Is there an easy way to modify the hexbin package to do this for me?

For example:

```
library(hexbin)
x <- replicate(9, rnorm(10000), simplify=FALSE)
y <- replicate(9, rnorm(10000), simplify=FALSE)
h <- mapply(hexbin, x, y)
par(mfrow=c(3,3))
lapply(h, plot)
```

This code doesn't display a grid of hexbin plots with common cell counts, but I'd like it to.

Comment: Agreed, not immediately obvious what I meant. What I meant by "common cell counts" is this idea that if a cell of a specific size or hue (whatever we use to represent the number of observations falling in a specific bin) means a certain value in one plot, it should mean the same value in the next plot. So, black may represent 400 in the top left, but if black represents 40 in the bottomright, I think it would be confusing and misleading as a graphic.

Answer (score 2):

hexbin objects are plotted using grid graphics so your par(mfrow=c(3,3)) does not do anything. Each graph is plotted on a separate page. To get the details of the plot options:

```
?gplot.hexbin
```

In this case, we want to set maxcnt to the largest cell count:

```
lapply(h, plot, maxcnt=max(unlist(lapply(h, function(x) max(x@count)))))
```

This will apply the same legend to each graph.